# Explain why this strange javascript code works

Tags: javascript

```
function get_denomination(){
    return "Fabrice Petard";
}

function auto_flatterie(flatterie){ // 
   return this.get_denomination() + " est " + flatterie + " !";
}

console.debug(auto_flatterie("le plus intelligent")); // affiche  "Fabrice Petard est le plus intelligent !"
```

Can you explain to what "this" is bound to and why this.get_denomination doesn't throw any error ?

Comment: Please read https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this.

Comment: This might also be helpful to you http://www.robertsosinski.com/2009/04/28/binding-scope-in-javascript/ , it's discussing the case you're describing

Comment: You probably want to run your javascript in [`strict mode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Strict_mode), where [this code would in fact throw an error](http://jsfiddle.net/mYecU/). Strict mode would also protect you from other poor language decisicions such as implicit globals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the code you posted, `this` is the global `window` object.  When you create a function in the default global scope (like `get_denomination`) it gets attached as a property to the `window` object.

Comment: Only if the function is global which it seems to be in this case.

Comment: I did not mean `this`, I was referring to, *"when you create a function (...) it gets attached to the `window` object"*, which can be understood such as *any* function becomes a property of the global object, which is not true. Inexperienced developers might find this confusing.

Answer (score 3):

`this` binds to the `window` object. The method `get_denomination` is registered at the `window` object.

Comment: Only if it is global which it seems to be in this case.

Comment: Yes, I suppose a bigger discussion of scoping would be a fuller answer, but I wanted to only explain the current behavior.